# Checkbox array to string help: Implode $_POST and return values to same $_POST?

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode

I'm trying to store the results of a short form to a flat-file (e.g. a .text file). The file will be imported into Excel as a delimited file. The form has checkboxes so it can be set into an array:

```
<input type="hidden" name="roflz" value="noresponse">
<input type="checkbox" name="roflz[]" value="Yesroflz" id="Yesroflz" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['roflz']) && $_SESSION['rolfz'] == "Yesroflz") { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>> <label for="Yesroflz">Yesroflz</label> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="roflz[]" value="Moreroflz" id="Moreroflz" <?php if (isset($_SESSION['roflz']) && $_SESSION['roflz'] == "Moreroflz") { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>> <label for="Moreroflz">Moreroflz</label><br />
```

Is it possible to implode an array from `$_POST['rolfz']` and return the results to `$_POST['rolfz']`? The desired result is a string that I can store into a text file. See code below:

```
<?php
// begin the session
ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'private');
session_start();
//Turn checkboxes (an array) into a string. So we can later store it into a strong. 
if(isset($_POST['rolfz'])){
    $_POST['rolfz'] = implode(",",$_POST['rolfz']);
    }
```

The overall goal is to store all the values from $_SESSION into a text file. However, when I try to run the code I get "Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\cgi-bin\thankyou.php on line 14". The error telling me that in the below code I'm trying to use an array as a string.

```
// Take each input name and create a variable for it
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
$_SESSION[$k]=$v;
}
//Implodes the array so we can store the values as a string (not the variables name though!)
$results = implode("|", $_SESSION);
//Open up the file that we will store the collected information to
$datafile=fopen("V1.txt","a") or exit("Unable to open file to record data!");
//Write the data on a new line ("\r\n") so we don't over-write the existing data
fwrite($datafile, "\r\n".$results);
//Close out the file
fclose($datafile);
//reset session variables and destroy the session
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
?>
```

If what I'm doing is wrong or impossible, is it possible to use an alternative statement instead for the `foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)` so that it ignores `$_POST['rolfz']`? That way I can handle `$_POST['rolfz']` on its own?

**Edit (5/10/11):** 
Before imploding:

```
array(5) { ["date"]=> string(10) "05/10/2011" ["time"]=> string(11) "09:11:20 AM" ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" ["lolz"]=> string(7) "YesLOLZ" ["roflz"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "Yesroflz" [1]=> string(7) "Noroflz" } }
```

After imploding:

```
array(5) { ["date"]=> string(10) "05/10/2011" ["time"]=> string(11) "09:11:20 AM" ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" ["lolz"]=> string(7) "YesLOLZ" ["roflz"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "Yesroflz" [1]=> string(7) "Noroflz" } }
```

**Edit (5/10/11):** 
Please see Michael's solution if you are attempting to do a similar solution. And note that I'm an idiot and used the wrong checkbox name in my code (it should be roflz not rolfz).

Comment: Is there a reason you're cooking up your own means of representing `$_SESSION` as a string to write to your file instead of using the `serialize()` function, which is designed for that purpose? http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: The file is the end point in terms of the data collection. I would use a database but can't due to environment restrictions. I did try to use `serialize()` at one point but if I recall it ended up with a bunch of text unreadable to most people. Since others will be importing the text file into Excel (don't have the ability to write directly to an excel file) and using pipe delimination to break it into columns I'm trying to do it this way.

Comment: I see. It wasn't clear from your post that you needed the output to be human-readable or usable as a CSV, etc.

Comment: Ah, good point. I'll edit the post to make it clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: Be sure to `var_dump($_SESSION)` before attempting to `implode()` it, in case there's some other array already in there.

So it seems your error is that your `$_POST` contains an array, and you are converting `$_POST` directly into `$_SESSION` then attempting to `implode()` it into a string as is.  `implode()` trips over that array.

You can ignore `$_SESSION['rolfz']` quite simply:

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
  if ($k != 'rolfz') {
    $_SESSION[$k]=$v;
  }
}
```

Then handle it with other means as you have suggested.

Better yet, store `$_POST` into `$_SESSION` as is, but use a different temporary array to filter out `rolfz`:

```
$_SESSION = $_POST; // will overwrite anything already in $_SESSION

$tmp_array = array();
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
  if ($k != 'rolfz') {
    $tmp_array[$k]=$v;
  }
}

// Then implode() $tmp_array and write to file.
```

**EDIT 5/11/2011**:
Since overwriting `$_POST` doesn't seem to be working, try using an intermediate value and removing the orignial `rolfz` key:

```
if (isset($_POST['rolfz'])) {
  $temp = implode(",", $_POST['rolfz']);
  unset($_POST['rolfz']);
  $_POST['rolfz'] = $temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I can't use the second solution since that would remove all the other variables residing in the _SESSION array. I've used the first, and then attempted to turn the imploded $_POST as a $_SESSION[variable]. However, it doesn't seem to work.  `if(isset($_POST['rolfz'])){
    $_SESSION['rolfz'] = implode(",", $_POST['rolfz']);
 }`

Comment: Edit: Please see below main post.

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot. I just realized what the error was. The checkboxes' names are roflz while I've been using rolfz. Sorry for wasting any more of your time. Thanks for the help! I'm learning PHP as I go.